# I can't create multiple products with my mysqli query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with php/MySQL query. 
I am working on a small car rental website. In my database I have a table that contains "cars" and another table for "products".

- "car" Table has the following columns: id_car, description, photo, color.
- "product" table has the following columns: id_product, date_start, date_end, id_car, price

As you can see, "product" table is used to prepare products that are ready for rent so I need to make them display in a table for site users.

In order to create a new product, I need to register the following information in table "product":

- id_product (Auto Increment)
- start date
- end date (basically the car available from "start date" to "end date")
- id_car (I have this information from the "car" table so no problem for this. See query below)
- price (I can add this from the form as well).

## Here is the problem:

Let's say I want I create a new product for id_car 1. When I do this for the first time, evrything works fine but when I try to create a new product for this same (id_car) with different dates I see NO record in database!!?

Here is my query:

### SELECT QUERY (to get id_car)

Example: I want to create a new product for a car that has id_car = 1.

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT id_car FROM car WHERE id_car='1'")

$car = $result->fetch_assoc();

$id_car = $car['id_car'];
// When I get my $id_car variable, I can now use it in my second query to create a new product.
```

### INSERT QUERY

```
"INSERT INTO product (id_product, date_start, date_end, id_car, price)
 VALUES ('$id_product', '$date_start', '$date_end', '$id_car', '$price')");
```

Please tell me why I can't create multiple products for this car? Note that in PHPMyAdmin I can create many products for this car. The query works fine

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `car` (
  `id_car` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `photo` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `color` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_car`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product` (
  `id_product` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date_start` datetime NOT NULL,
  `date_end` datetime NOT NULL,
  `id_car` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `prix` int(5) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_product`),
  KEY `id_car` (`id_car`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

Regards,

Comment: Are you sure `('$id_product', '$date_start', '$date_end', '$id_car', '$price')")` values are not empty ? What is the error ?

Comment: There is no error. First time the product is created and I can see records in DDB but when I try to create another product with new dates nothing happens?? As if I am allowed to create just 1 product for a given id_car..?? Each car has to be available for different dates ..

Comment: Why do you notify "id_product" at insert if it is auto_increment ? Arent you trying to insert multiple products with the same ID ? So MySQL ll stop the insert.

Comment: Could you include the output of the `SHOW CREATE TABLE product` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE car` queries, so we know what the tables actually look like (including unique constraints and AI fields...)

Comment: "INSERT INTO product (date_start, date_end, id_car, price) VALUES ('$date_start', '$date_end', '$id_car', '$price')");

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `car` (
  `id_car` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `photo` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `color` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_car`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product` (
  `id_product` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date_start` datetime NOT NULL,
  `date_end` datetime NOT NULL,
  `id_car` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `prix` int(5) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_product`),
  KEY `id_car` (`id_car`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;